# Linux script Loop

Tags: linux, variables, loops, for-loop

I want to create a loop in Linux script that will go thru the folders in one directory and will copy photos to one folder and will overwrite photos that have the same name. Can anyone point me in the write direction?

Answer (score 3):

```
find /path/to/source -type f -exec cp -f {} /path/to/destination \;
```

Would that work? Keep in mind, that will overwrite files without asking.

If you want it to confirm with you before overwriting, use the -i flag (for interactive mode) in the `cp` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/source -type f | xargs -I {} file {} | grep <JPEG or image type> | cut -d ":" -f1 | xargs -I {} cp -rf {} /path/to/destination
```

With this you can find tune your copy with selecting only the image type.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need not to loop through folders for finding photos using script, `find` command will do that job for you.

Try using `find` with `xargs` and `cp`

```
find source_dir -type f -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} cp -f {} dest_dir
```

Replace `*.jpg` with format of your photo files. (e.g. `*.png` etc.)

Note the use of `-f` option of `cp`, since you want to overwrite photos with the same name